# 'Have licence' vs. 'Have /a/ licence'

Tags: nouns, articles

I wrote in an essay: 'We now have licence to move beyond [an idea].' Grammarly flagged this up, saying that I should add an article before 'licence'. Is this true, or is 'licence' interchangeable with 'permission' or 'freedom' in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, Grammerly can not think beyond the literal. Your sentence:

**'We now have license to move beyond [an idea].**

is correct.  From the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/107943?redirectedFrom=have%20license#eid39414167): **license**

> liberty (to do something), leave, permission. Now somewhat rare. †Also
> occasionally exemption from (something). †Formerly often in licence
> and leave; by, with, without (a person's) licence; to get, give,
> **have**, obtain, take licence.

Your usage implies permission is or has been given.

Comment: In case anybody is confused about the spelling, the question was in British English,and lbf has replied in American English.